# Extend an existsing object method

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have an object:

```
MyObj = new Class.create();
MyObj.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.myArg = null;
    },

    setArg: function(arg) {
        this.myArg = arg;

    },

    showArg: function () {
        alert(this.myArg);
    }
};

var x = new MyObj();
x.setArg('Something');
x.showArg();

x.setArg = function(arg) {
    //how to call here the original??
    alert('Here is my custom code')
}
```

It is created in a code what I can not overwrite.

What I want to do is to extend this existing object like this:

```
x.setArg = function(arg) {
        this.myArg = arg + ' a new cake';
}
```

I just do not want to copy the original code.

**UPDATE:**

I have nothing to do with the prototype. The object has already created.

Comment: i think this will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745021/javascript-decorator-pattern

Comment: Are you using a third-party library here, EG Prototype?  That first line does not look like vanilla JS.  Maybe worth adding a tag for that if it's the case.  And it would be good to indicate to people helping that you _do_ or _don't_ want to stick to using that lib and its methods.

Comment: Yes, "I am" using prototype, added the tag, thanks. Basically it is a magento2 thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here

**Option One**

Override only the method

```js
var MyObj = function(){};
MyObj.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.myArg = null;
    },

    setArg: function(arg) {
        this.myArg = arg;

    },

    showArg: function () {
        alert(this.myArg);
    }
};

var oldMethod = MyObj.prototype.setArg;
MyObj.prototype.setArg = function(arg) {
    oldMethod.call(this,arg)
    console.log(arg)
}


var x = new MyObj();
x.setArg('Something');
x.showArg();
```

**Option Two**

Extend the object then override any method you want

```js
var MyObj = function(){};
MyObj.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.myArg = null;
    },

    setArg: function(arg) {
        this.myArg = arg;

    },

    showArg: function () {
        alert(this.myArg);
    }
};


var MyNewObject = function() {
}

MyNewObject.prototype = new MyObj()
MyNewObject.prototype.setArg = function(arg) {
    MyObj.prototype.setArg.call(this,arg)
    console.log(arg)
}


var x = new MyNewObject();
x.setArg('Something');
x.showArg();
```

Comment: The problem is that I have nothing to do with the prototype. The object has already created. I need to use an existing object.